# How to give unique id for each button

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have buttons created by loop and each button it corresponds to a desk, so i have to able when i click a button i have to design spesific row of database

how i add buttons:

```
for (int i = 1; i < terasmasasayisi; i++)
    {
        var buttonteras = new Button
        {
            Text = i.ToString(),
            HeightRequest = 45,
            WidthRequest = 45,
            Margin = 5,
            BorderRadius = 100,
        };``

        teras.Children.Add(button);
    }
```

If i can set a relationship between the table number and i(desknumber), I can do this according to the id from my database.

im so confused

Comment: each button already has a unique Text value, use that

Comment: no after clicking a button a new page will show up and then i have to do changes on database

Comment: You are not explaining this well.  Does it just need to be a unique random value, or does it need to correspond to some existing value from the database?  What does Button1 do differently from ButtonX?

Comment: button 1 and button 2 will do the same thing but on different lines

Comment: if you don't answer my questions I can't help you.  There is not enough information here to explain what you are doing or where you are stuck.  If you don't add more information this will just get closed.

Comment: ok i will try 

I have buttons and each button it corresponds to a desk, so i have to able when i click a button i have to design spesific row of database

Comment: so each button needs to have the DeskID assigned to it?  How do you know which button corresponds to which desk?

Comment: exactly thats the point!

Comment: @JasonIf If i can set a relationship between the table number and i(desknumber), I can do this according to the id from my database.

Comment: Create listview with template and button inside. Populate listview with db. Pass  model to button click, and you can get db Id from row directly.

Comment: You could define a custom button and add the property like ID .

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom button

```
public class MyIDButton : Button
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty ButtonIDProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ButtonId), typeof(int), typeof(MyIDButton), 999);

    public int ButtonId
    {
       get => (int)GetValue(ButtonIDProperty);
       set => SetValue(ButtonIDProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Then use it like

```
var buttonteras = new MyIDButton 
        {
            Text = i.ToString(),
            HeightRequest = 45,
            WidthRequest = 45,
            Margin = 5,
            ButtonId = 1, //whatever your value
            BorderRadius = 100,
        };
```