# How can i change of button background color on another form in xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

**hello**

```
 for (int i = 1; i < terasmasasayisi; i++)
        {

            var buttonteras = new Button
            {

                Text = i.ToString(),
                HeightRequest = 45,
                WidthRequest = 45,
                Margin = 5,
                CornerRadius = 100,
            };
            buttonteras.Clicked += butonteras; 
            teras.Children.Add(buttonteras);

           async void butonteras(object o, EventArgs args)

                {  

                secilenmasa = buttonteras.Text;
                secilenkonum = "Teras";
                await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new menu());

                }

            }
```

i create multiple buttons in that way terasmasasayisi is counts how many row i have in database

and theese buttons directs me to another page on that page after clicking to a button i have to change the first buttons background color, how can i do that?

Comment: Do you want to change the bg color of the first button in `buttonteras` ?

Comment: yes sir thats what i need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check the following code

Use MessagingCenter

```
 for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {

            var buttonteras = new Button
            {

                Text = i.ToString(),
                HeightRequest = 45,
                WidthRequest = 45,
                Margin = 5,
                CornerRadius = 100,
            };
            buttonteras.Clicked += butonteras;
            stack.Children.Add(buttonteras);



        }

        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Object,View>(this,"click",(obj,view)=>
        {
            var childrens = stack.Children;

            for (int i = 0; i < childrens.Count; i++)
            {
                var element = childrens[i];

                var type = element.GetType();
                if (element == view)
                {
                    element.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;


                }
            }
        });
```

```
async void butonteras(object o, EventArgs args)
{
  //...
    var button = o as Button;
    await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new menu(button));


}
```

And in menu, when click button .

```
View Element;

public menu(View element)
{
   Element = element;
   InitializeComponent();
}
```

```
MessagingCenter.Send<Object,View>(this, "click",Element);
```

Comment: thanks for helping but i have to manage the color of buttons from another form and this is not working :(

Comment: D0 you will return the first page after you click the button in new form ?

Comment: im trying to fit this in my code i will give feedback

Comment: Did you add `break;` ?

Answer (score -1):

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<siparis>(this, "click", (obj) =>
            {
            var childrens = bahce.Children;

            for (int i = 0; i < childrens.Count; i++)
            {

                    var element = childrens[i];

                    var type = element.GetType();

                    if (element.GetType().ToString() == "Xamarin.Forms.Button")
                    {
                        element.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
                        break;

                    }
                }
            });

            async void bahcebuton(object o, EventArgs args)
            {


                secilenmasa = buttonbahce.Text;
                secilenkonum = "Bahçe";
                await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new menu());


            }
```

and other form

```
if (masterpage.secilenkonum == "Bahçe")
        {
            MessagingCenter.Send<siparis>(this, "click");
        }
```

**now it doesnt makes all buttons red but now makes only first button red**

Comment: of course i will, issue is now it doesnt makes all buttons red but now makes only first button red, not the button i choose

Comment: you tried so hard im sorry to tell that but that is not working

Comment: You could share your sample so that I can test it on my side .

Comment: i actually said everything about project but its complex i will try another method and i will check your answer as right answer

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT i can share project file if you want but you cant see anything without database and database is on local server

Comment: OK , use static data .And don't forget to remove your personal info like account and password

Comment: i did can you give me your mail adress for sending the file?

Comment: You could post it to github . I could not provide my info to you because of policy

Comment: And did you solve the issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60465994/how-to-give-unique-id-for-each-button here  ?

Comment: the issues are connected i asked that because i had to change the right color of button and i cant post to githup because file is 47mb i zipped and uploading to a download site

https://www.dosya.tc/server26/fqpea2/App1.zip.html + i have to change the red color to gray after 30-60 mins automaticcially

Comment: OK , I will check it as soon as possible .

Comment: I will share the sample tomorrow

Comment: https://github.com/luczha/demo123 Your demo has some issues and I had improved it , now it works .

Comment: I dont know how you did but it works great! You are great man!